# How to get type of currency of sobject field via REST API?

Tags: rest-api

do you know how to get type of currency(euro, usd .etc) of sobject field via REST API?

Comment: did you check `CurrencyISOCode`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field is called `CurrencyISOCode` and you can get it the same way you would get any other field in the object (via a SoQL statement, presumably).

Keep in mind that this field *does not exist* if Multi-Currency has not been enabled in an org so if you are developing a solution that hits several different Orgs and some don't have the feature enabled then you should probably check for its existence first.

==Update==

As @sfdcfox pointed out in comments, each record can have a different value for that field. For example, an Opportunity record might have a ISO code of `USD`, while another one might have `EUR`.

Comment: You might mention the *record* determines the currency type, not the individual field.

Comment: Good point, tho I assumed the terminology issues came out of a language barrier, not ignorance.

Comment: in case of Multi-Currency has not been enabled, where to check currency type?

Comment: In that case you use the Org currency.

Comment: I guess it would be this query /services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Organization/id but there is no currency  field? I miss something?

Comment: @AndrewG Did you manage to find the answer? I'm struggling with it now, can't find any info about org currency in Rest api with single-currency mode.

Answer (score 1):

For when multi-currency is not enabled : the defaultCurrencyIsoCode is part of the response for uri `services/data/v.../connect/organization`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_connect.htm?q=connect/organization#org_resource